# Swift 5.1 console app in Linux : keyboard arrow Up/Down behaviour

Tags: swift

I'd like to add bash-like behaviour for my console app - when I press Arrow Up/Down I can see the previous commands entered. Here is the way I handle user input :

```
while true {
    print(">> ", terminator : "")

    if let inputCli = readLine() {
        let lowerCasedInput = inputCli.lowercased()
        if lowerCasedInput == "exit" {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

What is the way to achieve this?

If I press Up and Down I see the following output :

> ^[[A^[[B

How can I handle these press events?

Comment: This is a requirement, not a question. What do you want us to help you with? i'd suggest you add the command as received to an array to keep the history

Comment: Added a question - I thought it is clear from the topic

Comment: We just needed to know which specific part you need help with, otherwise its quite broad

Comment: Well, for the moment I have no idea concerning handling Up/Down events. May be you'd point me to some external library or a standard library solution. For example in Python there is a "readline" package that is able to solve this problem...

Comment: I am not aware of any particular package that solves this issue on iOS, but there is a readLine method in the Swift standard library. Maybe you could use that. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641199-readline

Comment: readLine gives a String optional after you press Enter. But the question is how to handle Arrow Up/Down without pressing Enter? Like the way I get it in Ubuntu console...

Comment: what your explaining isn't really making much sense to me. you are writing a console application that will run in a terminal and you are trying to replicate terminal functionality within the console app?.  I think you would actually need to write your own terminal, with its own UI to do what you are explaining. then you can listen to key events and control what is displayed

Comment: "you are trying to replicate terminal functionality within the console app?"
Not exactly - my app supports a restricted set of commands to execute. I don't need to access OS api. I don't need UI also - it's a command line interface only. And I need to support a history for only these custom commands. The goal of this app - is to limit user API with the set I provide. But there should be no difference from user experience

Comment: what i am saying is that your app runs within the terminal, the terminal has a UI and responds to the key events such as up/down and displays previous commands and stuff. its working at a higher level than your console app. so your console app doesn't receive any information until the terminal decides you can, which is pretty much just on the user pressing enter. meaning what your trying isn't really possible without creating your own terminal and UI and responding to the events yourself.

Comment: hm, if it were a C++ app I would use  tcgetattr/tcsetattr to set unbuffered terminal mode, so I would have an access to key press events. Is there something similar for swift under Linux?

Comment: from within a standard terminal, running a standard console application. you **cannot** listen for key press events. **nothing** is sent to your console application until you hit enter. it doesn't matter which language or library you use. the terminal handles user interaction and sends you a *line* when it decides to. you read the whole, completed line with readLine. thats the way it works.

Comment: Please have a look at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html. There is so-called "Raw mode" which can be used to turn off echo mode in terminal. I can be used to listen to key press events.

Comment: ok, try to do something with that, update us on how you get on :) good luck